# How do you remotely log into RStudio Server (Open Source) as an admin?

Tags: 18.04, server, rstudio

This is largely an RStudio Server question, but I'm performing these operations in Ubuntu, so posting here as well.

I'm running RStudio Server Open Source (version 2021.09.0+351, Ghost Orchid) on a Linux server (Ubuntu, 18.04. 6 LTS, Bionic Beaver). I have 2 accounts on the server, both of which have `sudo` privileges. I'm trying to update the default library path on one of the accounts (using the "Tools/Install libraries..." dialog; see [here](https://www.accelebrate.com/library/how-to-articles/r-rstudio-library)), but when I open the dialog, I cannot specify a different library path. To address this, I'm trying to run RStudio Server as an admin remotely on my server. How do I do this?

I could not find a solution to this in the [RStudio Server documentation](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/). [This page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server) recommends specifying the `r-libs-user` field in the `/etc/rstudio/rsession.conf` file; however, even after doing this and restarting rstudio-server, the default library path for the user in question remains unchanged.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Something missing. Is there not a VM involved here?

Comment: No, no VM. Just RStudio Server running on a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me, you are solving problem using wrong method.

You have to create shared library folder for both users

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/R-packages
sudo chown -R user1:user2 /var/R-packages
sudo chmod -R u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx /var/R-packages
```

and then install R packages there by commands like

`install.packages('bookdown', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', lib='/var/R-packages')`

using any *user1* or *user2* account.

Then you'll need to inform RStudio about this custom R packages library by commands like shown below:

```
p <- .libPaths()
p <- c(p, '/var/R-packages')
.libPaths(p)

require(bookdown)
```

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert.  I agree with the suggestion of using shared library folders across users--this is probably the most logical solution. 

I was looking for a means of changing default libraries using the RStudio interface, but `.libPaths()` seems to be the best means of achieving this.